# Raspberry pi 3 Ubuntu Mate 16.04.2 -> segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, ubuntu-16.04, raspberry-pi3

I've been trying to install Ubuntu Mate 16.04.2 from http://ubuntu-mate.org/download/1 in a Raspberry pi 3 B (not B+). I'm able to download the img from the site, write it into a MicroSD, boot (with correct screens: Resized partition, all the 'first boot' stuff like usename, wifi, etc), reboot for wifi, and login. No faults, no errors.

Then, when I run a 'sudo apt update' I get 512 package updates. If then I run a 'sudo apt upgrade' it downloads all the packages and start installing. But during the installation it simply stops, get a 'segmentation fault' and from here all the commands on the Terminal are 'segmentation fault'. If I reboot, on the next boot I get a 'kernel panic'.

Tried several cards to see if it was a Hardware issue, but all gets to the same end. Also I downloaded several times the img because of corrupted download. Again, same end.

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?